# How to split a column in more columns in psql?

Tags: postgresql, split

I want to make a view using columns from another and I have this column:

```
stack_prices : 1=1.95 | 3=1.89 | 10=1.85
```

And I want to make (for this example) 6 columns like:

```
stack_size1: 1  stack_price1: 1.95 
stack_size2: 3  stack_price2: 1.89 
stack_size3: 10 stack_price3: 1.85
```

I've tried with substring, and kinda works, but is hardcoded for this example:

```
substr(cp.stack_prices,3,4) AS company_product_price1,
substr(cp.stack_prices,1,1) AS company_product_stack_size1 etc...
```

I actually want to split after `|` and `=`.

Comment: You should consider keeping your database relational, as most SQL engines aren't well suited for this sort of transformation.

Comment: A database field must contain only data and not a set of data

Comment: Unfortunately for me I can't modify the table with stack_prices column

Comment: Yes, it is. I've found that I can use regexp_substr, but it seems that I can't use it in psql.

Answer (score 0):

You need do it in two stages:

1. split by `'|'`
2. split by `'='`

You can use `string_to_array` like this:

```
SELECT
    'stack_size'|| id || ': ' || trim(split2[1]),
    'stack_price'|| id || ': ' || trim(split2[2])
FROM  (
    SELECT  row_number() OVER() AS id, string_to_array(sub.split1, '=') as split2
    FROM (
       (SELECT unnest(string_to_array(stack_prices, '|')) AS split1 FROM company_product)
    ) sub
) sub
```

Edit:

Above query's out put will be exacly as you write in the question. It could by use to proccess one row only (ex you could put this in stored procedure)

If you want more generic solution to have 6 columns in one row there's one to go:

```
SELECT
    stack_prices,
    split1_1[1] as ss1, split1_1[2] as sp1,
    split1_2[1] as ss2, split1_2[2] as sp2,
    split1_3[1] as ss3, split1_3[2] as sp3
FROM (
    SELECT
        stack_prices,
        regexp_split_to_array(split1[1], E'=') as split1_1,
        regexp_split_to_array(split1[1], E'=') as split1_2,
        regexp_split_to_array(split1[1], E'=') as split1_3
    FROM (
        select
            stack_prices,
            regexp_split_to_array(stack_prices, E'\\ \\|\\ ') as split1 
        from company_product
    ) sub
) sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working.

select split_part((split_part(cp.stack_prices, '|', 1)), '=', 1) from company_product cp;
    select split_part((split_part(cp.stack_prices, '|', 1)), '=', 2) from company_product cp;

select split_part((split_part(cp.stack_prices, '|', 2)), '=', 1) from company_product cp;
    select split_part((split_part(cp.stack_prices, '|', 2)), '=', 2) from company_product cp;

select split_part((split_part(cp.stack_prices, '|', 3)), '=', 1) from company_product cp;
    select split_part((split_part(cp.stack_prices, '|', 3)), '=', 2) from company_product cp;

Comment: Using `string_to_array` and `unnest` can give you more generic solution for future reuse. Consider [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33231870/5404196)

Answer (score 0):

Ugly problem: ugly solution:

```
CREATE TABLE stack_prices (
        ugly_string text
        );

INSERT INTO stack_prices ( ugly_string ) VALUES
 ('1=1.95 | 3=1.89 | 10=1.85' );

SELECT ugly_string AS orig
, regexp_replace(ugly_string, ' *([0-9])*=.*', '\1') AS n1
, regexp_replace(ugly_string, ' *[0-9]*=([0-9.]*).*', '\1') AS v1
, regexp_replace(ugly_string, ' *[0-9]*=[0-9.]* \| ([0-9]*)=.*', '\1') AS n2
, regexp_replace(ugly_string, ' *[0-9]*=[0-9.]* \| [0-9]*=([0-9.]*) \|.*', '\1') AS v2
, regexp_replace(ugly_string, ' *[0-9]*=[0-9.]* \| [0-9]*=[0-9.]* \| ([0-9]*).*', '\1') AS n3
, regexp_replace(ugly_string, ' *[0-9]*=[0-9.]* \| [0-9]*=[0-9.]* \| [0-9]*=([0-9.]*).*', '\1') AS v3
FROM stack_prices
        ;
```

---

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
           orig            | n1 |  v1  | n2 |  v2  | n3 |  v3  
---------------------------+----+------+----+------+----+------
 1=1.95 | 3=1.89 | 10=1.85 | 1  | 1.95 | 3  | 1.89 | 10 | 1.85
(1 row)
```